# How to call broadcast receiver only once in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hello I faced the same problem I have 1 broadcast receiver from that I started 1 service which is for getting messages from inbox. After that from that service I send those messages to the particular number. And for the sending message I used the same code as above(posted by John). My problem is, when I send message the toast Message "SMS SENT" will come continuously. So how can I receive that only once?

I am stuck on this please can anybody suggest me where I am wrong?

Thanks.

Here I posted my code:-

```
package z.z.z;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
{
    private SmsMessage[] msgs;
    private String strNo,strMsgText;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            msgs = null;
            String str = "";         

            if (bundle != null)
            {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
                {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += ":";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    strNo = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();    
                    strMsgText = msgs[i].getDisplayMessageBody();

                }

                context.startService(new Intent(context,IncomingSMSService.class));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

IncomingSMSService:-

```
package z.z.z;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import z.z.z.Global;
import z.z.z.SMSService;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class IncomingSMSService extends Service  
{

    private String TAG = "IncomingSMSService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        /* start service */

        Log.d(TAG ,"****** in service onCreate  **----- ");
        super.onCreate();

        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG ,"****** in service try  **----- ");
            /* Read SMS from INBOX  */
            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");      
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);      
            String sms = "";      
            while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {          
                    sms += "From :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(11)+"\n";
    //              Log.d(TAG, "in SMS Service sms in loop :: "+ sms);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "in SMS Service sms :: "+ sms);


            Log.d(TAG ,"********** reverseNum ******  "+ Global.destNo);
            ArrayList<String> ayyMsg = new ArrayList<String>();
            ayyMsg.add(sms);
            SMSService.sendSMS(getBaseContext(), ayyMsg, Global.destNo);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
```

SendSMS

```
   package z.z.z;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import z.z.z.common.RMAReceiver;

    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class SMSService 
    {

        static String TAG = "SMSService";
        static String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        static String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    //  static Context mContext;
        static RMAReceiver rmaReceiver = null;
        public static void sendSMS(Context context,ArrayList<String> message, String destNumber)
        {   
            try
            {



                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

                PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                ArrayList<PendingIntent> ayySentPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                ayySentPI.add(sentPI);

                ArrayList<PendingIntent> ayyDeliveredPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                ayyDeliveredPI.add(deliveredPI);

                receiver(context);

                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

                sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(destNumber, null, message, ayySentPI, ayyDeliveredPI);

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

**receiver**:-

    public static void receiver(Context context)
        {
            rmaReceiver = RMAReceiver.getSingleInstance();
            context.registerReceiver(rmaReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            context.registerReceiver(rmaReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));  
        }
```

RMAReceiver

```
package z.z.z;

import z.z.z.SMSService;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RMAReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private static RMAReceiver singleInstance = null;
    String msg;

    private RMAReceiver()
    {       
    }

    public static RMAReceiver getSingleInstance()
    {
        if(singleInstance == null) singleInstance = new RMAReceiver();
        return singleInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        System.out.println("Result Code: "+getResultCode());
//      resultCode = getResultCode();
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                msg = "SMS sent/delivered";
//              Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent/delivered", 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              SMSService.sendSMS(context, "SMS sent/delivered", Global.confirmNo);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                msg = "Generic failure";
//              Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              SMSService.sendSMS(context, "Generic failure", Global.confirmNo);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                msg = "No service";
//              Toast.makeText(context, "No service", 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              SMSService.sendSMS(context, "No service", Global.confirmNo);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                msg = "Null PDU";
//              Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              SMSService.sendSMS(context, "No service", Global.confirmNo);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                msg = "Radio off";
//              Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              SMSService.sendSMS(context, "No service", Global.confirmNo);
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                msg = "SMS not delivered";
//              Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered", 
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              SMSService.sendSMS(context, "No service", Global.confirmNo);
                break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SMSService.sendSMS(context, msg, Global.confirmNo);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have set it up that way. Your `IncomingSMSService` calls your `SMSService.sendSMS` function which registers your `SMSReceiver` which sends an intent to start your `IncomingSMSService` all over again and so on.

Try removing one link of this chain and see if it fixes your repetition problem.

Comment: Actually I have to send message that "SMS SEND" to particular number as a notification. Thats why I again sendSMS from RMAReceiver.

Comment: The problem is, you are using your custom class `SMSService.sendSMS` which registers the receivers for sent and delivery notifications. To send the notification texts, use the vanilla `SMSManager.sendTextMessage` so that you do not get an infinite loop of texts and sent notifications for the sent notifications for the sent notifications of those texts, etc.

Comment: @Craigy I have a similar sort of problem, I set my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006044/broadcast-reciever-looping-first-message… I cannot locate where the infinite loop is coming from, I have double checked the path of intents yet it is seemingly one-directional, no cyclical logic as anddev had...yet the problem persists, an infinite listing of the first message sent in a group